# How to insert multiple rows in a table using oracle stored procedure without parameters

Tags: oracle, procedure, plsqldeveloper

I have a table:

```
test_1(id int, f_name varchar(20),age int).
```

I want to populate this table with values  using a stored procedure.

```
(1,'josh',23),(2,'jack',34),(3,'liam',45).
```

I know how to do this using simple SQL, but want to know how it can be done using a stored procedure. I used a stored procedure below but that didn't work and gave me an error. Below is the error and the procedure below it. The stored procedure has been compiled but with errors.

> Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IN" when expecting one of the following:
>      `<an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>`
>   current delete exists prior "

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_test_1(IN a_val int not null,IN b_val varchar(20),IN c_val int(2))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test_1
(id,f_name,age) VALUES (a_val ,b_val ,c_val);
END
```

Then I tried calling the procedure, but it didn't work:

```
CALL insert_test_1(1,'josh',23)
```

I need some help for this to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your procedure won't compile. You can't run it until it compiles. Your tags say you're using PLSQL Developer. Are you actually using the Allround Automations IDE or did you think the tag meant something more generic?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter definitions are incorrect. The parameter mode (IN, OUT, INOUT) must follow the parameter name.

You cannot put a scale or precision on a parameter definition - you can only specify the basic type (e.g. INT, VARCHAR, NUMBER, etc).

You also can't put a NOT NULL constraint on a parameter definition.

Also note - VARCHAR2 is preferred to VARCHAR, as the Oracle definition of VARCHAR may change at some time in the future. VARCHAR2's semantics are guaranteed not to change in the future.

Thus, you should use

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_test_1(a_val IN INT,
                                          b_val IN VARCHAR2,
                                          c_val IN INT) IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test_1 (id,f_name,age) VALUES (a_val ,b_val ,c_val);
END;
```

If there are errors from a compilation you can retrieve them by fetching data from the ALL_ERRORS view, similar to:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ALL_ERRORS
  WHERE NAME = 'INSERT_TEST_1';
```

Note that the name must be capitalized when fetching data from ALL_ERRORS. Internally, all names in Oracle are CAPITALIZED unless "Quoted".

Best of luck.